# Using requirejs in typescript file

Tags: typescript

I would like to convert main.js file to TypeScript for learning purposes.

After having renamed the file to main.ts, I get a design time warning on this line:

```
define('knockout', ko); //Cannot find name define.
```

How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to let TypeScript know about external libraries. The easiest way to do that is through [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/requirejs/require.d.ts).
This link will take you to the require.js deffinitions for TypeScript. A .d.ts file is used to let TypeScript know about the API available through a libary, more info [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files).

You can get any definitelyTyped definition files though nuGet in VisualStudio.

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
```

In VS, you can drag and drop the d.ts file into the .tx file and it will create the above code for.